# Magento 2 : TypeError: data.some is not a function

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, adminmenu

In Magento 2 admin menu 'Add new' page open but showing just loader image. Getting below error in console log. 
Anyone have any idea please share.

```
TypeError: data.some is not a function
winTop = win.scrollTop();
```

in Below file

```
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/static.js
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this ?

Comment: @frank which page you have getting this error in admin area , is there custom extension or default magento page ?

Comment: This error is occur because of default value not identify  in admin field.

Answer (score 7):

This was caused by a different issue for me. I was getting this error when trying to create a new cart price rule.

There was a patch that hadn't been run in the composer.json and a re-deploy resolved it :

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-ui": {
                "some.data is not a function": "patches/module-ui-patch-1.diff"
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the diff of this patch :

```
diff --git a/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js b/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js
index 0c266b9..22fe498 100644
--- a/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js
+++ b/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js
@@ -64,16 +64,17 @@ define([
     function findFirst(data) {
         var value;

-        data.some(function (node) {
-            value = node.value;
-
-            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
-                value = findFirst(value);
-            }
+        if (data instanceof Array) {
+            data.some(function (node) {
+                value = node.value;

-            return !_.isUndefined(value);
-        });
+                if (Array.isArray(value)) {
+                    value = findFirst(value);
+                }

+                return !_.isUndefined(value);
+            });
+        }
         return value;
     }
```

Comment: How am I meant to install this patch?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/project/project-patch.html

Comment: add this to your composer json

"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-ui": {
                "some.data is not a function": "patches/module-ui-patch-1.diff"
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @Frank, can you explain it clearly, I am also facing same issue, not getting how to start this

Comment: @Frank, already i have like in my composer.json file,  "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }

Comment: @jafar it's the patches part that is significant : 

"patches": {
            "magento/module-ui": {
                "some.data is not a function": "patches/module-ui-patch-1.diff"
            }
}

This should be resolved in magento by now. However, i've decided to move on from magento, so can't say for certain.

Comment: @Frank, no it is not fixed, facing same issue

Comment: @Frank, in which path you moved the patch?

Comment: @jafar - As i said, not working with Magento anymore and this was a very  long time ago. Patches belong in magento-root/patches you can find the patches on their website, but composer should handle that for you. The second code block is the entirety of the patch file however, so create the file patches/module-ui-patch-1.diff, dump the contents of my second code block in it and run composer update. Failing that, if the changes aren't already in the magento core, you could always override view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js and apply the patch manually.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, here is how to apply a patch : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/project/project-patch.html